# Refresh a tab using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the link to my previous question: [passing id name on click using ajax to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609748/passing-id-name-on-click-using-ajax-to-php)

I have three tabs that show ajax based search results on click.
How can I refresh a tab(clear search results) when I click any other tab.
Say, I have search results in tab-1 and I click tab-2 or three, I want the first tab to return to its initial stage and so on.

I tried slide up and .hide functions but they don't seem to work for this.

Any ideas?

```
$("input[name='tab-group-1']").click(function() {
if ($("input[name='tab-group-1']:checked").val() == 'tab-1') {
$("#display_results_1").show();
$("#display_results_2").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_2']")
                        .attr("value", "");
$("#display_results_3").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_3']")
                        .attr("value", "");
}else if {
($("input[name='tab-group-1']:checked").val() == 'tab-2') {

$("#display_results_2").show();
$("#display_results_1").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_1']")
                        .attr("value", "");
$("#display_results_3").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_3']")
                        .attr("value", "");
}
else{
$("#display_results_3").show(); 
$("#display_results_1").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_1']")
                        .attr("value", "");
$("#display_results_2").hide();
$("input[name='display_results_2']")
                        .attr("value", "");
}
});
```

Comment: Please show some code to indicate the structure and demonstrate what you're trying.  `.slideUp()` and `.hide()` will style elements to not be visible, but they won't remove or refresh them.  If you're using an AJAX call to fetch the data, the success handler for that call should remove the old results from the DOM and add the new ones.

Comment: @david: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @alice: Well, what do you mean by "refresh"?  Are you trying to fetch new data from the server, or just show/hide the other tabs?  If the latter, what isn't working for you?  On what line of code does the observed behavior differ from expected behavior?  If the former, where is your AJAX call?

Comment: I posted link to my previous question, that has my entire jquery and ajax call. When I say refresh, I want tabs to return to their initial state, where they don't display previous results. User can return to those tabs and search again.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @alice: Also, I just tried formatting your code for readability and it makes no sense to me.  What is `if else`?  What is that line after it trying to do?  Does this code even parse without error?

Comment: @alice: Each question on Stack Overflow should contain relevant information for what's being asked.  You can certainly link to another question for reference, but if there's code relevant to this question it should be in this question.  Back to the point, for the "refresh" then it sounds like you want to `.remove()` elements, not just hide them.  Just make sure you only remove the specific ones you don't want anymore, instead of removing the entire tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I was out of my station. I tried .empty() and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

He probably meant:

```
function tabrefresh(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
};
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Fair point, but as you might notice a comment has not gotten a response. I dont think that would help. But search results might find this unanswered. (as it did for me), This might point people in the right direction or give them something else to look in to.